# How to perform calculations with unknown matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to check if there are matrices B,C $\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ such that $$B^2C^2 - C^2B^2 = A.$$
$A$ is another $3\times3$ matix and looks something like:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
10 & 3 & 4  \\
2 & 5 & 6 \\
6 & 15 & 18  \end{array} \right)
$$

Playing around with wolframalpha seems to show that $B^2C^2 - C^2B^2 = 0$ but I am not sure about it.

This would be true if $BC = CB$, but there is no necessarily such restriction.
How would one proceed with such a calculation?

Comment: Can you show us how wolframalpha made you believe that $B^2C^2-C^2B^2=0$?

Comment: For that particular $A$ the answer is no since Trace $(B^2C^2-C^2B^2)=0$.

Comment: @5xum I tried it with 2x2 arrays, (maybe completely wrong, I am new to wolfram too) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+[[a%2Cb]%2C[d%2Cz]]+*+[[a%2Cb]%2C[d%2Cz]]+%29+*+%28+[[j%2Ck]%2C[m%2Cn]]+*+[[j%2Ck]%2C[m%2Cn]]+%29+-++%28+[[j%2Ck]%2C[m%2Cn]]+*+[[j%2Ck]%2C[m%2Cn]]+%29+*%28+[[a%2Cb]%2C[d%2Cz]]+*+[[a%2Cb]%2C[d%2Cz]]+%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all square matrices $X,Y$ you have
$$\operatorname{Trace} (XY-YX)=0$$
putting $X=C^2, Y=B^2$ you get that $\operatorname{Trace} (B^2C^2-C^2B^2)=0$, while $A$ has non-zero trace. So your equation has no solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I didn't know about the Trace. Are there also other ways to show this, without checking the Trace?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't exist any such matrix $B$ and $C$. Because the trace of the left hand side i.e $trace(B^2C^2-C^2B^2)=0$ where as the trace of $A$ is nonzero